# Request for LIMS technical info

Tags: java

I have experience in THERMO LIMS (Laboratory information management system), and now I have switched to Labvantage  LIMS 6.0 version.

I would like to understand the skill set which are required essentially to support / develop Labvantage LIMS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is essentiall a professional / skills development question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

To support Labvantage I'd say having an IT background is a plus as you'll have a better understanding of the software package. If you want to configure the system, you can follow a web page designer course (adding fields to pages, extending data model...). More information can be found on their website: http://www.labvantage.com/services/training/web-page-designer/

If you want to customise Labvantage, you need to know Java and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ThermoFisher. For labvantage these skills are useful.

- Java for custom functionality (what they call Actions).
- JSP if    your customers want complex UI that can't be made from template    - SDC/SDI pages and other page wizards.
- Javascript mainly for    validation.    Database skills - to go through existing data, so the    workflow you design may make sense.
  Also useful for designing    reports that customers may need
- LabVantage concepts - SDC/ SDI /    Pages/ PropertyList etc
- For integration: knowlege of SOAP interface    points.

I'd be interested in knowing about thermofisher system, let me know.